# Usar clausula "WHERE IN ()" NO SPRING BOOT JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Alguém sabe como posso usar alguma clausula semelhante ao `WHERE IN` no `spring jpa`?

exemplo:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "Delete from table where id in(:ids)",nativeQuery=true)
    void deleteByIdid(@Param("ids") String var);
```

Já tentei enviar uma `String` parecida com essa:

```
5151,5151,51515,884,8484.
```

Porém não funciona.

**Mensagem**

```
couldn't execute statement.
```

Acredito que na hora de passar o parâmetro o `spring` coloca a `variável` entre aspas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o spring data e fazer dynamic queries https://stackoverflow.com/a/18996367/4219136

Exemplo:

```
findByInventoryIdIn(List<Long> inventoryIdList)
```

Você pode obter mais informações na documentação do Spring Data - http://bit.ly/1XADXf2

Se preferir continuar utilizando query methods, creio que será necessário alterar o parâmetro para uma lista, exemplo:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Table t WHERE t.id IN :ids")
Set<Table> findByTableIn(Set<Long> ids);
```

No entanto, entendo que é preferível a primeira opção :)

Você pode adaptar essa opção para o seu DELETE

Comment: era exatamente isso que eu precisava, obrigado.

Comment: @RobertoOliveira fico feliz em ajudar! Pode marcar a resposta como correta? :)

Comment: @RobertoOliveira pode marcar a resposta como correta?